# C# Silverlight Equivlant of Windows Form Method?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, sockets

What is the equivlant of this:

```
while (Offset < packet.Data.Length)
{
    Offset += m_Socket.Receive(packet.Data, Offset, packet.Data.Length - Offset, SocketFlags.None);
}
```

In Siliverlight? That is Windows Form and does not work with Silverlight :/ Any helped would be appreciated.

Thanks

What the function does is, on the "completed" sub, I catch 4 bytes which is a header length from my server, after I caught those 4 bytes I want to go into the endReceive method which gets the rest of the packets length.

How would I do this in Silverlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight does not have synchronous Socket methods. You will need to use [Socket.ReceiveAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync.aspx).

Good example here: [Pushing Data to a Silverlight Client with Sockets](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/04/13/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-sockets-part-ii.aspx).

**[Edit]** A basic idea to do something like this:

```
var e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
e.Completed += SocketReceiveCompleted;
Socket.ReceiveAsync(e);

private void SocketReceiveCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    Offset += e.BytesTransferred;
    if (Offset > packet.Data.Length)
    {
        Socket.Close(); // or do whatever you need to do after your while loop
        return;
    }
    Array.Copy(e.Buffer, 0, packet.Data, Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that wasn't what I asking. I was asking, what would be the equivlant to the function above using ReceiveAsync or whatever method Silverlight offers? It's the only part I can't figure out in my app. Here's what's going on. I'm getting 4 bytes from my server which contains the packet length, after I've got the 4 bytes I want to grab the rest of the data based on how long of length I put. Which is why the function above worked on Windows Programs but not on Silverlight.

Comment: @Eric - I know you would like to get the code that is nice and working. However, firstly it is difficult to do with that much details that you provided. Secondly, if take a little effort and read about async socket receive approach you can implement it better and faster as you are the one who knows the requirements. I updated the answer with the async code that matches your async code.